# How to index plain text files for search in Sphinx

Tags: search, sphinx, plaintext

I scanned dozens of articles and forum threads, looked through official documentation, but couldn't find an answer. This [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-sphinx-on-ubuntu-14-04) sounds promising, since is says that `The data to be indexed can generally come from very different sources: SQL databases, plain text files, HTML files`, but unfortunately as all other articles and forum threads it is devoted to `MySQL`.

It is rather strange to hear that `Sphinx` is so cool, it can do this and that, it can do practically anything you want with any data source you like. But where are all those examples with data sources other than `MySQL` ? Just one tiniest and trivial step-by-step example of `Sphinx` configuration when you want to scan the easiest source of data in the world - plain text files. Let's say, I've installed `Sphinx` and want to scan my home directory (recursively) to find all plain text files, containing "Hello world". What should I do to implement this?

**Prerequisites**:

- `Ubuntu`
- `sudo apt-get install sphinxsearch`
- ... what is next????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at this before proceeding [Sphinx without SQL!](http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=11964) .

Ideally I would do this.

We are going to use Sphinx's [sql_file_field](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-sql-file-field) to index a table with file path. Here is the PHP script to create a table with file path for a particular directory(scandir).

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","database");

mysqli_query($con,"CREATE TABLE fileindex ( id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,text VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$dir = scandir('/absolute/path/to/your/dir/');

foreach ($dir as $entry) {
    if (!is_dir($entry)) {
        $path= "/absolute/path/to/your/dir/$entry";
        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO fileindex ( text ) VALUES ( '$path' )");
    }
}

mysqli_close($con);


?>
```

Below code is sphinx.conf file to index the table with filepath. Notice sql_file_field which will index those files which are specified in the text(filepath) column

```
source src1
{

    type            = mysql
    sql_host        = localhost
    sql_user        = root
    sql_pass        = password
    sql_db          = filetest
    sql_port        = 3306  # optional, default is 3306
    sql_query_pre = SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=utf8
    sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
    sql_query       = SELECT id,text from fileindex
    sql_file_field = text

}

index filename
{
    source          = src1
    path            = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/files
    docinfo         = extern
}

indexer
{
    mem_limit   = 128M
}

searchd
{
    log                 = /var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd.log
    pid_file            = /var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd.pid
}
```

After creating table, saving the sphinx.conf in /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf just run sudo indexer filename --rotate, your indexes are ready! Type search and then keyword to get results.

Comment: That is absolutely great! This answer deserves +100500 points.

Comment: By the way, can you, please, advise me how to update index? I mean the following - by the time we typed one keyword, one of the documents could have changed (in terms of sql - `text` field had changed). If you cover this theme on updating index, your answer will deserve +100500 ^ 100500 points =) Thanks!

Comment: Open Terminal > crontab -e  and setup a cron to re-index data every ....say 10 minutes. 

`*/10 * * * * indexer filename --rotate`

I have never tried using [RT indexes](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/rt-overview.html) on files. You can give it a shot!